# Cannot set Vue JS data variable from custom event called

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, dom-events

I've used the Vue CLI to build a web component that I'm using as a plugin. I've attached some events to the web component and am trying to call these where my plugin is installed. I'm using the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) constructor to trigger an event, but for some reason my data isn't being set.

```js
mounted () (
  document.addEventListener('myplugin:modal:show', function (evt) {
    console.log('event triggered -> modal show')
    this.modal.isShown = true // isn't setting when event called
  }, false)
)
```

I'm calling it from my project like this:

```js
document.dispatchEvent(new Event('myplugin:modal:show'))
```

I'm not quite sure when I call my event why my Vue JS data variable isn't being set, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a Vue.js component or a web-component? What is the role of Vue.js here?

Comment: Vue JS component built using the official Vue CLI, exported as a web component into a vanilla JS application. The events serve as a way of communicating between a non vue js project and the plugin

Comment: How are you making sure event is triggered after component is mounted?

Comment: FYI, I've just solved this by defining `const self = this` outside of the event listener, and then referencing `self.modal.isShown`